# The set of Systems of Distinct Representatives in a finite universe

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, inclusion-exclusion, bipartite-graphs

Given a collection of finite sets, how might one think about finding the set (unordered) of all systems of distinct representatives for the collection?

*Example:*

$S$: {{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}

Unordered SDRs: {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}}

Notice that {2, 1} is already counted by "{1, 2}" as the SDRs are unordered.

*System of Distinct Representatives Definition*:

Let $S=(S_1,S_2,...,S_n)$ be a collection of sets. A System of Distinct Representatives (SDR) of $S$ is a collection of elements $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ such that $x_i∈S_i$ and $x_i≠x_j$ for all $i,j∈\{1,2,...,n\}$ where $i≠j$

Comment: S is not a set.  It is a finite sequence.

Comment: Updated the question, thank you

Comment: Double usage of S.

Comment: Thank you, again. Have I it right this time?

Comment: I don't have time to write up an answer right now, but [here](http://research.nii.ac.jp/~uno/papers/isaac97web.pdf) is an algorithm, though phrased in the language of bipartite matchings. It is efficient in the sense of generating each solution quickly, but there may be exponentially many solutions, so it may take a long time to find them all.

Comment: @Misha unless I'm mistaken, the linked paper deals with ordered SDRs and not unordered. Maximum matchings seem to be equivalent to ordered SDRs.

Comment: @ColinMcDonagh What's the distinction you're making?

Comment: @MishaLavrov if we have vertices {1}, {2} and {3} as one bipartition and vertices {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3} as the other, two complete matchings are {1}->{1, 2}, {2}->{1, 2, 3} and {2}->{1, 2}, {1}->{1, 2, 3}. These are equivalent to the two SDRs {1, 2} and {2, 1}. However, I'm looking for unordered SDRs, so I only want to count {1, 2} or {2, 1} once

Comment: If $U$ is a sequence, then what does it mean for $S_i$ to be subsets of the sequence $U$? Also, shouldn't your representatives actually represent something? Maybe you left out requiring that $x_i$ be in $S_i$?

Comment: Happy to see the corrections have been made. Now, I wonder – it doesn't say anywhere that the $S_i$ are finite sets, and if they aren't then there could be infinitely many SDR, so what does finding the set of all SDR mean in that case? or are you happy to restrict to the case where all the $S_i$ are finite?

Comment: @Gerry Hi Gerry, I'll update the question to state that $S_i$ are finite sets. Thank you

Comment: But I'll leave the definition of an SDR as general, and just restrict the collection in the problem statement to finite sets